# C# WPF which method is called when I call a window's show()?

Tags: c#

I have window A and window B. In window A I call B.show(). I want to know in window B which method is called and I want to load data when B is showing up. thanks,

Comment: What do you mean "in window B which method is called"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be surprized, but when you call `B.Show()`, the method which is called is `Show()`.

About loading additional data after window `B` is shown, you may subscribe to its `Loaded` event (see answer of @masenkablast). The better idea would be perhaps to derive from `Window` class and bind to the needed data in XAML. (You are using WPF, not WinForms, I suppose.)

Comment: +1 I derive from the Window class all the time to do cool things

Answer (score 5):

You can always listen to the "Loaded" event:

```
BWindow.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(BWindow_Loaded);        

void BWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Your Code here
}
```

Then in your `AWindow` call

```
BWindow.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to have a Property which is set before B.Show() is called. This way you can always get the method which invokes the show method based on the property.